# How to access firebase db sub object elements?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase db structure is given below,

```
users
fb-user-key1
    user1-details1
    Tags
        Tag-key1    
            "name":"value"
        Tag-key2
            "name":"value"

fb-user-key2
    user1-details2
    Tags
        Tag-key1    
            "name":"value"
```

Tag-Key1 & user-key's are generated by firebase with push(). firebase code to access the content is,

```
var fbref = firebase.database().ref("users");
fbref.child("Tags").on("child_added", function(e){
  var Tagobj = e.val().name;
  console.log(Tagobj);
});
```

This one is not returning anything. I am not able to access name:value pair in the above data structure.
`
adding modified code,

```
firebase.database().ref("users").on("child_added",function(e‌​) { var Tagobj = e.val().Tags; });
```

Output of the above code is [output data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXJx.png)

How to access that name value pairs?? firebase keys are issue?
Not getting, where I am wrong. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: What is your use case? Are `Tags` for a user ever updated after a user is created? Do you have a store in your app where you can add new values and trigger re-rendering?

Comment: `Tags` is not the child of `users`.

Comment: @ArneHugo, yes tags are updated with new name value pairs frequently.

Comment: @torazaburo, Thanks for clarifying, I have missed that. But I want to access "name: value" pair. How?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tags` is a child property of each user, then you have to read it off of each user object.

If you want all `Tags` for all users, assuming `Tags` for each user is not updated after a user is created, you can do this:

```js
tagsPerUserId = {};

firebase.datatabs().ref('users').on('child_added', function(snap) {
    tagsPerUserId[snap.key] = snap.value().Tags;
    // TODO: Notify view that tagerPerUserId is updated and needs to be re-rendered
    console.log(`Tags for userId ${snap.key}: ${snap.value().Tags}`);
});
```

This way you will also get `Tags` of new users when they are created, but you will not get updates to `Tags` of existing users.

Comment: Added new code and output format to my question. Please check

Comment: In you example [example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXJx.png) you seem to get the Tags for a user like I would expect. I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you trying to get the name for each user from inside `Tags`?

Comment: yes I am tring to get the name for each user under Tags

Comment: So do you just want an array of names? Then you can do `Object.values(Tags)` (If you do use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) you should polyfill it to make sure it works in all browsers.)